# gnome-shell 3.16 window titles

Tags: gnome-shell, window-decoration, metacity

Before 3.16, it was easy to remove the window titles from maximized windows - just editing the metacity-theme.xml file. However, 3.16 is using client side decorations, and metacity has no control over the window decorations. Is there another way of hiding the window titles, or at least making them much smaller?

Answer (score 6):

You can minimize (not remove) the title bar by removing the padding from it. Just add the following code to the file `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (create if not exists):

```
.maximized .header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

.maximized .header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Apart from that you can use the GNOME extension `Maximus Two` to get completely rid of title bars on maximized windows. A version supporting 3.16 is available from here: http://michaeltunnell.com/blog/16-linux/56-my-updated-316-packages-for-gnome-extensions

Here is a very short script that does more or less the same as `Maximus Two` (using the `_GTK_HIDE_TITLEBAR_WHEN_MAXIMIZED` atom): https://gist.github.com/tuxor1337/74e76d3d153c67593454 You need to run it on GNOME startup and leave it running in the background (might be helpful: [Start Script when Gnome Starts Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up)).

By the way, here you can get an idea of how to remove the title bar from *all* windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156300/xprop-set-motif-wm-hints-hides-maximized-window

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I downgraded to 3.14 and I will try this when I re-upgrade to 3.16.  I know about the Maximus Two, however it is buggy. I tried but couldn't fix it, so I was looking for another solution.

Comment: I know about this "black bar" bug of the `_GTK_HIDE_TITLEBAR_WHEN_MAXIMIZED` atom. But it must be an upstream issue and it occurs pretty unfrequently to me. Since the whole theme engine changed with 3.16 there's not much hope for another solution. The only thing I can think of is the `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` atom (see last link in my post).

Comment: @thomas I'm getting that *all* the time. I have to resize every time a window starts fullscreen.

Comment: @thomas thanks for the sample CSS! One question though: could you detail *how* you found those classes? Just by scrubbing the css of GTK, or is there an inspector that would help?

Comment: I found the CSS somewhere on the internet some time ago, don't remember the url, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the extension [Maximus NG](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1026/maximus-ng/), which did not install successfully. But via its comments I found [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) which works better. However it displays a cross to close the windows among the status buttons in the top right, which I find annoying. <strike>But after disabling Pixel Saver again, the top bar of maximized windows has not reappeared, and the cross has disappeared. So everything is perfect for me now.</strike> *EDIT*: This effect only lasts the current session.

I use Gnome 3.18, on Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 LTS Beta 1.

Comment: I am using the pixel saver for quite sometime actually, and I like the buttons you mentioned. But if you don't like, you can probably `cd $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me` and edit `extension.js`. Try removing the 4 lines containing the word "Buttons".

Answer (score 0):

Pixel saver helped on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then press "super" button and type "tweaks" - select "tweaks", go to "Extensions" - enable "Pixel saver" radio button.
That's it